# a4j:ajax nested on h:inputText prevents execution of h:commandButton action on first click

Tags: ajax4jsf

I have the following code:

```
...
<h:inputText
    id="valorMoedaLocal"
    value="#{pagamentoRegistrarMB.valorMoedaLocal}"
    styleClass="right dinheiro"
    size="12"
    maxlength="12">
    <f:convertNumber
        type="number"
        minFractionDigits="2"
        maxFractionDigits="2" />
    <a4j:ajax
        event="change"
        execute="valorMoedaLocal" 
        render="valorPagamento"
        listener="#{pagamentoRegistrarMB.calculaValorRealOuroCorrecao}" />
</h:inputText>
<h:outputText
    id="valorPagamento"
    value="#{pagamentoRegistrarMB.valorPagamento}"
    maxlength="12">
    <f:convertNumber
        type="number"
        minFractionDigits="2"
        maxFractionDigits="2" />
</h:outputText>
...
<h:commandButton
    id="cbCorrigir"
    value="#{messages['label.corrigir.pagto']}"
    action="#{pagamentoRegistrarMB.validarCorrecao}"
    disabled="#{empty pagamentoRegistrarMB.idRequerimentoMovimentoCorrigir}">
    <f:param
        name="id"
        value="#{pagamentoRegistrarMB.bean.id}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

If I change the content of field valorMoedaLocal and then I click on button cbCorrigir, the ajax nested on the inputText is executed and the action from button cbCorrigir is not executed; it requires a second click to execute.

This happens because when I click on the button, the inputText looses focus and this caauses its ajax to be executed, preventing following executions. Is there a way to avoid this undesired behavior?

Comment: this is the intentional behaviour of `event="change"`. can you share the exact scenario you want to achieve?

Comment: @tt_emrah I want both the ajax nested on the inputText and the action from button cbCorrigir be executed in sequence.

Comment: @tt_emrah From user's point of view, this should be transparent, i.e., he shouldn't be required to click twice on a button to get its task performed...

Comment: did you try using `a4j:commandButton` instead of `h:commandButton`? it can save you from the "second click" thing. however, if the actions need to be executed in a specific order, i don't think this is the correct approach to do it. you can trigger an `a4j:jsFunction` in `oncomplete` phase of an `a4j:commandButton`, for example.